# Encountering race condition using openMP in C

Tags: c, matrix, openmp, race-condition

Here is the section of my code where I am running into a race condition. I'm just trying to copy the values of the matrix "matxOriginal" into the matrix "cluster0", but, when run on multiple threads using openMP, the sample values printed for "cluster0" is different from "matxOriginal". 
Both matrix has been dynamically allocated and are both 698 x 9 matrix.

Also, I would like to keep the use and purpose of the "cluster0IndexCounter" variable for a different use outside of what I'm posting. So if you can, please let me know how to make this work.

```
double **matxGen(int row, int col)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    double **m;
    m=(double **) malloc(row*col*sizeof(double *));
    for (i; i<row; i++)
    {
      m[i]=(double *) malloc(col*sizeof(double ));
      for (j=0; j<col; j++)
      {
          m[i][j]=j+i;
      }
    }
    return m;
}


double **emptyMatxGen(int row, int col)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    double **m;
    m=(double **) malloc(row*col*sizeof(double *));
    for (i; i<row; i++)
    {
      m[i]=(double *) malloc(col*sizeof(double ));
      for (j=0; j<col; j++)
      {
          m[i][j]=0.0;
      }
    }
    return m;
}


int main()
{
    int x, i, j, tid, row=699, col=9,
    cluster0IndexCounter=0;
    double **matxOriginal, **matx, **cluster0;

    matxOriginal=matxGen(row, col); 
    matx=matxGen(row, col);

    double *centerPoint0=matx[99]; 
    cluster0=emptyMatxGen(row, col);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(x, j, tid) schedule(static) reduction(+:cluster0IndexCounter)
    for (x=0; x<=698; x++)
    {

       for (j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
           cluster0[cluster0IndexCounter][j]=matxOriginal[x][j];

        }

        cluster0IndexCounter=cluster0IndexCounter+1;

    }


printf("cluster0: %f, %f, %f, %f, %f\n", cluster0[9][0], cluster0[9][1], cluster0[9][2], cluster0[9][3], cluster0[9][4]);

free(cluster0);
free(matxOriginal);
free(matx);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide more of the code.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can  help.

Comment: I just updated it so now you can see the full code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP, but don't you need `#pragma omp serial` before the `printf()` call?

Comment: It's unnecessary in this case since the #pragma omp parallel for directive only applies to the for loop underneath. After the for loop ends, the following statements become serial again automatically.

Comment: You are right, this does seem to cause some kind of confusion. If I use x instead of the cluster0IndexCounter, then it will work. However, do you know any ways to make this work using the cluster0IndexCounter?

Comment: You seem to be missing some required header includes, particularly `<stdlib.h>`, as evidenced by you needing to cast the values returned by `malloc()`.  I recommend that you read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).